# Apache kafka broker consuming messages intended for someone else

Tags: apache-kafka

I've a local Apache Kafka setup and there are total 2 broker (id - 0 and 1) on port 9092 and 9093.
I created a topic and published the messages using this command:

```
bin/kafka-console.-producer.sh --broker-list localhost:9092 --topic test
```

Then I consumed the messages on other terminal using the command:

```
bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --topic test
```

Till now everything is fine.
But when i type command -

```
bin/kafka-console.-producer.sh --broker-list localhost:9093 --topic test
```

and write some messages it is showing in the 2nd terminal where I've typed this command -

```
bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --topic test
```

Why port 9093 messages are publishing to 9092?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your cluster contains of two brokers. It is not important which host you use for initial connection. Using kafka client you don't specify from which broker you consume or to which your produce messages. Those hostname are only to discover whole list of kafka brokers (cluster)

According to documentation:
https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#producerconfigs
https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#consumerconfigs

bootstrap.servers::

> A list of host/port pairs to use for establishing the initial connection to the Kafka cluster. The client will make use of all servers irrespective of which servers are specified here for bootstrapping—this list only impacts the initial hosts used to discover the full set of servers.